# Edit and Continue Slow Visual Studio 2015 in C# Winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, edit-and-continue

My company recently upgraded from Visual Studio 2012 to Visual Studio 2015.
Our main application is a large c# winforms application.

In 2012, we could begin typing on a break point and it would almost instantaneously begin editing the file. However, in VS2015 it usually takes up to a minute or more before we are allowed to start making changes. Often Visual Studio GUI will show (Not Responding) during this time. Once the changes are finally made, it usually takes another 30+ seconds after we continue before the application becomes responsive.

Multiple members of our team are having this issue. What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Most likely a bug, as it is still relatively new software (as in the 2015 version).

Comment: I work on a very large WinForms app and yes, 2015 has some issues when it comes to a lot of things.  I do some work in 2015 but switch back to 2013 for the serious debugging stuff.

Comment: In a way. this question seems very similar to this though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952670/visual-studio-2012-winform-designer-is-very-slow?rq=1  And as the asker of that question answered his own question.... It will get better as they push out updates ti VS 2015.

Comment: I have this problem on a machine with raid 0 ssds, 32Gb and a good I7 cpu. It can be mind numbingly slow on even switching between windows at times.

Comment: In addition to daves comments, it also usually crashes VS if I "edit and continue".

Comment: E&C still dreadful with update 3 (WinForms, VB.NET)